# Name,Email Validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, validation

I'm looking for code that validates the Name and Email input's on `<Form onsubmit="return validate();">`

I want that username has only `A-Z`,`a-z` and *must* have an underscore`_`, email should have an `@`. How can I do it with jQuery?

**Form(example):**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="..." method="POST" onSubmit="return Check()" >
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Please enter your Name. (Must have underscore)" required>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('[name="submit"]').click(function(e){
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            if(re = /[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*/;) {
                $(".name").addClass("error");
                return false;
            } else {
                $(".name").removeClass("error");
                $(".name").addClass("success");
                return true;
            }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you actually looked for anything or tried anything yourself?

Comment: Looked yes, but can't find a right peace of code, that only chech A-Z and underscore.

Comment: Learn about regex: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: This in your code:
if(re = /[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*/;) {...}

should be replaced by:
re = /[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*/;
if (re.test('string_to_validate') {..code to run when string is valid..}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a valid email address:
[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

For your username is the same but your regex should be something like this:

```
re = /^[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*$/; //this always needs an underscore to be valid.
```

Just in case, this is the regex to accept anything az AZ and _ and nothing, it depends on your requirements:

```
re = /^[a-zA-Z_]*$/;
re = /^[a-zA-Z_]{3,}$/; //3 or more chars
```

To test your regex:

```
re = /^[a-zA-Z_]*$/;
return re.test('any_string_to_test'); //it returns true if your string is valid
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me, where should i put it on? if(...)?

Comment: Yes, if (re.test(ANY_STRING))

Comment: This example is working: https://jsfiddle.net/bsp3w3pu/8/
I've modified the regex.

Answer (score 3):

Using regex with jquery:

- Pass a string to RegExp or create a regex using the // syntax call
- regex.test(string) not string.test(regex)

In your code:

```
$(".name").on('keyup', function(e)
{
    var name = $(this).val();
    if(new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z_]+$/i).test(name)) // or with quotes -> new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z_]+$", 'i')
        $(this).addClass("error");
    else
        $(this).switchClass("error", "success", 1000, "easeInOutQuad");

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // to avoid sending form when syntax is wrong
});
```

And for email input, the following regex can do the job :

```
/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

**Or..**

To put a little bit of modernity, you can use [html5 email field type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

```
<input type="email" id="email">
```

Comment: Fixed code, with some perfection :)
first, you can test syntax validity without (or before) submit the form

Answer (score 3):

**Now using the advanced feature of HTML5 it's eaiser, you can simply do the validation as follow**:

```html
 <form action="" method="">
    <!-- Name containing only letters or _ -->
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z][[A-Za-z_]+" /> 
    <!-- using type email, will validate the email format for you-->
    Email: <input type="email" id="email" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Check [HERE](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) for more form validation features of HTML5.

Comment: I made a some new changes but both should work for you. I tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nR6yg/213/embedded/result/) and works fine.

Comment: I tried, but seems not working for me :x it skip's the name input than to validate it and check, but Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Polak i tried so, if i understand what you mean :x Sorry i'm new with javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('[name="submit"]').click(function(e){
            var name = document.getElementById("display_name").value;

            re = /[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*/;
            if (re.test(name) {
                //Things to do when the entry is valid.
                $(".NameCheck").removeClass("name_error");
                $(".NameCheck").addClass("name_success");
                return true;
            } else {
                //Things to do when the user name is not valid.
                $(".NameCheck").addClass("name_error");
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm new with stackoverflow, I've edited your answer, changing if (re.test("name")) {...... by if(re.test(name)){ ...without quotes and the if sentence was inverted. When you define a string variable foo=/...../; like a regex, then you can do things like foo.test('string to test'); and it will return true when the string is accepted by the regex.

Comment: now i can better understand, Thanks. But i getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { error. But thanks for help!

Comment: i think you forgot by editing from if(re.test(name) { to if(re.test(name)) {. Now it's working. Thanks very much for your help!